# Send email using parent mailenvelope with html link in the introduction with Excel VBA

Tags: html, vba, email, excel

It seems simple to add a html hyperlink to the body of an email using Outlook.

However I want to send a range of cells in the spreadsheet and a link to the file within the introduction.
Or a way to click on the image created in the email and hyperlink to the file.

I have the following code but the strbody if I designated the introduction as HTMLintroduction, it does not allow it.

```vb
Sub SendMail2()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
'Dim Sendrng As Range
    
Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:Q34")

If ActiveWorkbook.Path <> "" Then
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
              ActiveWorkbook.Name & "</B> is created.<br>" & _
              "Click on this link to open the file : " & _
              "<A HREF=""file://" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & _
              """>Link to the file</A>"

    With Sendrng
    
        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope
            .Introduction = strbody
    
            On Error Resume Next
            With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope.Item
                .To = "ac@uk.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = ActiveWorkbook.Name
                '.HTMLBody = strbody
                .Display   'or use .Send
            End With
        
        End With
        
    End With
        
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
Else
    MsgBox "Email not sent."
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** - (http://vba-useful.blogspot.com/2014/01/send-html-email-with-embedded-images.html)
The above link details how to make a jpg out of the range and send that in the email.

I found some very similar code that seems to use a slightly different method.  Perhaps it will work.  It seems to bypass the Mail.Envelope method you are attempting.  From [Ron de Bruin's](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail10.htm) page.  Unfortunately I can't test it on my current machine, so I hope it helps.

```
Sub Make_Outlook_Mail_With_File_Link()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Excel 2000-2013
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    If ActiveWorkbook.Path <> "" Then
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        strbody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
                  "Colleagues,<br><br>" & _
                  "I want to inform you that the next sales Order :<br><B>" & _
                  ActiveWorkbook.Name & "</B> is created.<br>" & _
                  "Click on this link to open the file : " & _
                  "<A HREF=""file://" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & _
                  """>Link to the file</A>" & _
                  "<br><br>Regards," & _
                  "<br><br>Account Management</font>"

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = ActiveWorkbook.Name
            .HTMLBody = strbody
            .Display   'or use .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
    Else
        MsgBox "The ActiveWorkbook does not have a path, Save the file first."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not achieve what I require.  I wish to send an image of the range to the email recipient and to have a link to that workbook.  Thus I have to use the mail envelope.  Or is there a way to make the image of the range a clickable hyperlink?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I've tested it with the website Link and not with your File-Structure, but it should work.

```
    Sub SendRangeAsPictureInMailWithHyperlink()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim Mail As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim ExcelRange As Range
    Dim InlineShape As Object

    ' Define the range in Excel that you want to copy
    Set ExcelRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName").Range("A1:C3")

    ' Copy the range as a picture
    ExcelRange.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    ' Create an Outlook instance
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Create a new email
    Set Mail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Mail
        .To = "recipient@example.com"   ' Set the recipient
        .Subject = "Subject of the Email"  ' Set the subject
        .HTMLBody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
                ActiveWorkbook.Name & "</B> is created.<br>" & _
                "Click on this picture to open the file :"  ' Set the body text of the email

        ' Display the email window
        .Display

        ' Insert picture at the end of the email text
        Set WordDoc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        WordDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf & vbCrLf  ' Adds two new lines at the end
        WordDoc.Range.Characters.Last.Paste
        Set InlineShape = WordDoc.InlineShapes(WordDoc.InlineShapes.Count)
        
        ' Add a hyperlink to the picture
        With WordDoc.Hyperlinks
            .Add Anchor:=InlineShape, Address:="file://" & ActiveWorkbook.fullname  'Or Address:="https://www.google.com/"
        End With
        
    End With

    ' Cleanup
    Set Mail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set ExcelRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

:)